# Keyboard Shortcut to Cycle through Windows of same Application in Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I would have expected this to be a very simple task: switching between windows of the same application, but I can't seem to find the shortcut to do it. I generally have several windows of applications like Chrome (each window holding all the tabs related to a particular topic).

The behaviour I am looking for is what is implemented in Mac OSX with the Cmd+~ keyboard shortcut.

Is there a way to achieve the same on Windows 7?

Comment: If the program is open on your task bar, hitting the Windows Key and the number of the location on the task bar will cycle through those applications. My web browser is pinned to the first location, so Windows Key + 1 cycles through my open web browser windows.

Comment: Ctrl + Tab will cycle through all the opened tab of browser..

Comment: @NickGarvey Well, that works but not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: You can download Easy Windows Switcher https://neosmart.net/EasySwitch/ it does just that. Very convenient app and it works with any Windows version

Comment: I didn't like any of the solutions proposed here, I was really looking for the equivalent of Alt+~ on MacOS and Ubuntu. In case someone was looking for the same thing as me, this is what worked for me: https://superuser.com/a/1721255/694663

Answer (score 105, accepted):

There is no such a keyboard shortcut but holding `Ctrl` + clicking on the icon in the taskbar repeatedly will cycle through that program's open windows.

Comment: That's great to find, although avoiding that click somehow would have been easier. Ubuntu does it so well.

Comment: Just found out holding `Shift` + clicking on the icon in the taskbar will create a new window of the program.

Answer (score 68):

See https://superuser.com/questions/435602/shortcut-in-windows-7-to-switch-between-same-applications-windows-like-cmd.

Scott's answer is the closest one I've found to doing this.  To summarize what he said:

**Win + n where n is the number position of the application in the TaskBar.**
Then to cycle through, keep Win down and press n again.

*(Updated thanks to @ZYinMD's comments - but also see their 1st comment)*

Comment: If you use `ctrl+win+n` it'd skip the thumbnail view and instantly switch exactly like mac

Comment: Good to know.  Note also that the thumbnails are only shown if a program has more than one window available; in that case, using `ctrl+win+n` will default to the first one.

Comment: Same can be said to `Win + n`. Speaking of which, you may want to edit your answer to be `win + n n n` instead of `win + n`. Also, n is not "the number of the application", it's "the position of the application on Taskbar", you may want to edit that too.

Comment: Ah gotcha, have updated so it's clearer.

Comment: Wow! That is even better than the way it works on mac. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This is the real thing, thank you (thumbs up and an upvote of course)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Windows 11. ctrl + win + n opens Narrator settings.

Comment: @NordlingArt I've confirmed that `ctrl + win + n` does work. It only opens narrator settings if you use the literal `n` key. `n` is a number. Take another look at this answer, "where n is the number position of the application in the TaskBar". Otherwise how would windows know which app you wanted to target?

Comment: @acat thank you for clarifying what n meant in this context. On Mac it targets the app currently in focus and toggles it’s windows one by one. I was hoping Windows did the same.

Answer (score 26):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> for fast switching without any GUI pop up

---

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: @mix3d no. test it yourself?

Comment: for me, thats all it does. Windows 10. Which could be the problem, since you posted for win7

Comment: Then i guess you have something overriding your  shortcuts.
Alt + Esc is an official windows 7,8,10 shortcut as seen here.https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: My mistake. It seemed to minimize because the window just "disappeared", but in reality it was "sent to the back" of all the other windows open. `Cycle through items in the order in which they were opened` is the official wording. Learned something new! It DOES still cycle between ALL open windows, however, and not application specific

Comment: This shortcut will only cycle through windows that are open on your current desktop if you have multiple desktops enabled on your machine. So if you're on desktop 1, it won't cycle over to desktop 2 to continue.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe related: If you want that the windows open directly when click on the stacked taskbar symbol (instead of opening the list), you can add the DWORD "`LastActiveClick`" to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```

and set it to 1.