# There a way to swapping instances of only the application VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, webstorm

I'm new to VSCode ([Visual Studio Code)](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and I'm coming from WebStorm.

When I used WebStorm I was able to use <kbd>Command + `</kbd> to swap instances of WebStorm windows. This behavior is also found in Chrome when you use that shortcut to switch between Chrome windows.

Is there a way to do this on VSCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options using VS Code:

- The `workbench.action.switchWindow` [keybinding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) to select the window to switch to. It is bound to <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> by default
- The [`workbench.action.quickSwitchWindow`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_14#_switch-window-improvements) command. Unlike `workbench.action.switchWindow`, it automatically switches windows when you release the keys. It is not bound by default but you can configure a keybinding for it.

The OS may also provide this:

- Mac: <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>
- [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175261/keyboard-shortcut-to-cycle-through-windows-of-same-application-in-windows-7)